# Using a custom cursor

Tags: java, swing, cursor

I've searched quite a few threads here but none have helped.

I have a few `JFrames` and each `JFrame` should have its own individual cursor, symbolizing which version of the program the user is using.
These files are in /AndroidToolkit/resources. The files are all .cur files, so they're actually proper cursors and not just images.

I've tried a few methods of doing this, but I have succeeded. I've tried using ImageIO, Toolkit, and my last try was:

```
Cursor cCur = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(getClass().getResource("../resources/ImpressionCursor.cur").getFile()., null, null);
```

How can I do this in an easy way, which is easy for other people to understand, without me having to always comment it with 10k lines?

Thanks in advance,
Beats

Comment: `getResource("../resources/ImpressionCursor.cur").getFile()` is a bad idea (the `getFile` part), `getResource` returns `URL`, so it should be usable with `ImageIcon`.  `createCustomCursor` doesn't take a `.cur` file, this is a OS dependent concept, this is why you are also required to provide a hotspot and name for the cursor.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Only one frame is loaded at any one time.

Comment: *"Only one frame is loaded at any one time."*  You seem to be using the GUI components to make some kind of 'wizard' API that is better suited to a single frame and a `CardLayout`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson No, no. Depending on whether there is a specific key in the settings, i.e. for the pro version, the Pro-UI is loaded. If no key, or an invalid key is found, the standard UI is loaded, if a developer key is found, the developer UI is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need, try this code 100% works for me on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, it should work for you too:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Toolkit toolKit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Image pencil = toolKit.getImage("pencil.gif");
        Cursor cursor = toolKit.createCustomCursor(pencil, new Point(0, 0), "Pencil");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cursor Test");
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.setCursor(cursor);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
```

this is the link for the gif file [click here](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-RIoQzkp9yYA/Tvp48FGjpvI/AAAAAAAABuE/2CAdLsmRdYc/s400/pencil.gif),
I hope that helps, Salam